# A* implementation

Tags: c++, algorithm, a-star

I wrote a little A* implementation by my own and would like to have some feedback ;)
The code is in OOP way, thus we can use an other pathfinding algorithm easily. The "Base" is just the interface class, thus is should not matter here.

Before we look at the code, let me say one or two senteces about it behaviour and motivations.

I like to write reusable code. Thus I looked for a possibility to abstract the behaviour of the algorithm from its underlying data model. Because of this I decided to implement a connection object for these two tasks. This is the "AreaVisitor". If you want to use this header, you have to subclass the "AreaVisitor" class and adapt it to your own data model. It doesn´t matter if you have a tiled 2d array or just some abstract nodes. You decide the important informations, the algorithm just use this in its usual way.
I know this is not as special as it sounds, but I think its useful to explain it first ;)

```
#pragma once

#include <memory>
#include <assert.h>
#include "Base.hpp"

namespace sfw {
namespace pathfinder {

    template <class Identifier>
    class AStar : public Base<Identifier>
    {
    public:
        template <class Identifier>
        class Node_ : sl::NonCopyable
        {
        private:
            const Node_* m_Parent = nullptr;

            Identifier m_ID;
            int m_Heuristic = 0;
            int m_Cost = 0;

        public:
            Node_(const Identifier& _id, int _cost, int _heuristic, const Node_* _parent) :
                m_ID(_id),
                m_Cost(std::move(_cost)),
                m_Heuristic(std::move(_heuristic)),
                m_Parent(_parent)
            {
                assert(m_Cost >= 0 && m_Heuristic >= 0);
            }

            Node_(Node_&& _node)
            {
                *this = std::move(_node);
            }

            Node_& operator =(Node_&& _node)
            {
                if (this != &_node)
                {
                    m_ID = std::move(_node.m_ID);
                    m_Cost = std::move(_node.m_Cost);
                    m_Heuristic = std::move(_node.m_Heuristic);
                    m_Parent = std::move(_node.m_Parent);
                }
                return *this;
            }

            const Identifier& getIdentifier() const
            {
                return m_ID;
            }

            int getCost() const
            {
                if (m_Parent)
                    return m_Parent->getCost() + m_Cost;
                return m_Cost;
            }

            int getHeuristic() const
            {
                return m_Heuristic;
            }

            int getFinalCost() const
            {
                return getCost() + getHeuristic();
            }

            const Node_* getParent() const
            {
                return m_Parent;
            }
        };
        using Node = Node_<Identifier>;
        using NodePtr = std::unique_ptr<Node>;

        template <class Identifier>
        class AreaVisitor_ : sl::NonCopyable
        {
        public:
            using Node = Node;
            using NodePtr = NodePtr;

            virtual ~AreaVisitor_() = default;

            virtual std::vector<NodePtr> getNeighborNodes(const Node& _pos) = 0;

            virtual int calculateHeuristic(const Identifier& _id) const = 0;
            virtual void setFinalChecked(const Node& _node) = 0;
            virtual void setInOpenList(const Node& _node) = 0;
            virtual bool isInOpenList(const Node& _node) = 0;
            virtual void removeFromOpenList(const Node& _node) = 0;
            virtual void setup(const Identifier& _destinationID) = 0;
        };
        using AreaVisitor = AreaVisitor_<Identifier>;
        using AreaVisitorPtr = std::unique_ptr<AreaVisitor>;

    private:
        AreaVisitorPtr m_AreaVisitor;

    public:
        AStar(AreaVisitorPtr&& _visitor) :
            m_AreaVisitor(std::move(_visitor))
        {
            assert(m_AreaVisitor);
        }

        Path calculatePath(const Identifier& _startID, const Identifier& _destinationID) const override
        {
            assert(m_AreaVisitor);
            m_AreaVisitor->setup(_destinationID);

            std::vector<NodePtr> openList, closedList;
            openList.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Node>(_startID, 0, m_AreaVisitor->calculateHeuristic(_startID), nullptr));
            while (!openList.empty())
            {
                auto node = std::move(openList.back());
                assert(node);
                openList.pop_back();
                m_AreaVisitor->removeFromOpenList(*node);

                // check if node is destination
                if (node->getIdentifier() == _destinationID)
                {
                    Path result;
                    for (const Node* curNode = node.get(); curNode != nullptr; curNode = curNode->getParent())
                        result.push_back(curNode->getIdentifier());
                    std::reverse(std::begin(result), std::end(result));
                    return std::move(result);
                }

                // fill open nodes with new neighbors
                for (auto& newNode : m_AreaVisitor->getNeighborNodes(*node))
                {
                    // try to override older node
                    if (m_AreaVisitor->isInOpenList(*newNode))
                    {
                        auto itr = std::find_if(std::begin(openList), std::end(openList), [&newNode](const NodePtr& _node){
                            return newNode->getIdentifier() == _node->getIdentifier();
                        });
                        if ((*itr)->getFinalCost() > newNode->getFinalCost())
                            *(*itr) = std::move(*newNode);
                    }
                    // insert new node
                    else
                    {
                        m_AreaVisitor->setInOpenList(*newNode);
                        openList.insert(std::lower_bound(std::rbegin(openList), std::rend(openList), newNode->getFinalCost(),
                            [](const NodePtr& _node, int _value){
                            return _node->getFinalCost() < _value;
                        }).base(), std::move(newNode));
                    }
                }

                // current node to closed list
                m_AreaVisitor->setFinalChecked(*node);
                closedList.push_back(std::move(node));
            }
            // return empty path
            return Path();
        }
    };
} // namespace pathfinder
} // namespace sfw
```

I would be really thankfull for any constructive feedback ;) I am also thankful about a better name than "AreaVisitor" for the AStar internal object.

Comment: I know A* is supposed to be a more efficient version of Dijkstra's algorithm but that's about all I know. Do you have a link to a description of the algorithm?

Comment: The A* searchs in a more efficient way. While the Dijkstra searchs the area in a radial way, the A* uses a estimated cost to the end node which reduces the affected nodes significant.
I think this one is a good tutorial to get a basic understanding how it works: http://www.raywenderlich.com/4946/introduction-to-a-pathfinding

Comment: More accurately. A* uses a heuristic that attempts to reduce the search area. Like all heuristics it attempts to optimize for a good solution trading an optimal solution for getting a result in a reasonable time. Do you need the optimal solution or just a probably good solution?

Comment: Don´t know if I understand you correctly, but the A* doesn´t optimize its runtime for its solution. The algorithm just uses the heuristic to reduce the affected tiles, the result is optimal as possible.

Comment: `Optimal as possible` is the keyword. Its not optimal. Dijkstra guarantees optimal but at the cost of a full search. A* tries to optimize the search area and does a best approximation. That's the whole point. You are getting a near optimal solution at a vastly reduced cost. Its just that sometimes its not optimal. Nothing is free in this world if you want optimal you have to pay for it.

Comment: This is wrong. The results are the same, you get exactly the same paths in each of these algorithms. The only difference is, Dijkstra covers the whole area, while A* tries to affect a minimum amount of nodes.

Comment: How can you get guarantee that you get the optimal result if you don't search the whole graph? By the way that's the definition of a Heuristic. It means its a best guess.

Comment: From the link you provide: `The closer the estimated movement cost is to the actual cost, the more accurate the final path will be. If the estimate is off, it is possible the path generated will not be the shortest (but it will probably be close).`

Comment: From [Heuristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heuristic) `problem solving, learning, or discovery that employs a practical method not guaranteed to be optimal or perfect, but sufficient for the immediate goals.`

Comment: PS. This is not a comment on your code. Just a comment on `A*`

Comment: This is a heuristic problem. If your heuristic is not correct/not optimal the path might be not optimal, too. So, you have to take about the heuristic. If this is optimal (for a 4 way 2d tiled map e.g. the manhattan method) the A* algorithm is exactly the same as in Dijkstra.
Please do not only use the link I posted. Look around in the internet. The A* is a specialization of Dijkstra. They only decide through the heuristic. The heuristic should never overestimate the cost. This is one problem you have to solve.

Comment: Seems like you don't understand the meaning of heuristic. Unless you scan the whole graph you can't know its the optimal solution. If you scan the whole graph you have not optimized Dijkstra its just as complex in terms of time. Now the 2D tile grid is a very simplistic graph and thus it is much more likely to find the optimal solution, but guaranteed I am not sure I believe that.

Comment: [A*_search_algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm)`For the algorithm to find the actual shortest path, the heuristic function must be **admissible**, meaning that it never overestimates the actual cost to get to the nearest goal node. The heuristic function is problem-specific and must be provided by the user of the algorithm.`

Comment: I do not see the problem. If you use 0 as your estimated cost for every single node, the algorithm is the same as Dijkstra. And yes of course a 2d map is a very simple graph, but this doesn´t matter anyway. You have to take care about your heuristic.

Comment: I never said there was a problem. Just chatting about A* and heuristics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not portable

```
#pragma once
```

Prefer include guards. Its not that hard to make them unique. Make sure they include the full namespace and file name

```
#ifndef SFW_PATHFINDER_ASTAR_H
#define SFW_PATHFINDER_ASTAR_H
// STUFF
#endif
```

Because you use template on the outside. You don't need to repeat it on the inside

```
    template <class Identifier>
    class AStar : public Base<Identifier>
    {
        ....
        template <class Identifier>
        class Node_ : sl::NonCopyable
        {...}
        using Node = Node_<Identifier>;
        using NodePtr = std::unique_ptr<Node>;

        template <class Identifier>
        class AreaVisitor_ : sl::NonCopyable
        {...};
        using AreaVisitor = AreaVisitor_<Identifier>;
        using AreaVisitorPtr = std::unique_ptr<AreaVisitor>;
```

Your internal nodes don't need to be templtized because they are part of an already templatized class. You can simplify the above with

```
    template <class Identifier>
    class AStar : public Base<Identifier>
    {
        ....
        class Node : sl::NonCopyable
        {...}
        using NodePtr = std::unique_ptr<Node>;

        class AreaVisitor : sl::NonCopyable
        {...};
        using AreaVisitorPtr = std::unique_ptr<AreaVisitor>;
```

Your use of underscore is perfectly correct. Unfortunately not all coders are aware of all the rules around underscore. So I prefer to avoid them, especially at the beginning of identifiers.

Your nodes use move semantics only. Which is fine. But your move constructor and assignment should be marked as `noexcept`. In your specific case it will make no difference but it is a good habit to get into (especially if these methods are actually noexcept).

```
            Node_(Node_&& _node) noexcept;
            Node_& operator =(Node_&& _node) noexcept;
```

This makes a difference when you have copy semantics and you are using standard containers. There are situations where the standard will rather use the copy than the move to preserve the strong exception guarantee.

I know you are trying to optimize the use of the assignment here.

```
            Node_& operator =(Node_&& _node)
            {
                if (this != &_node)
                {
                    m_ID = std::move(_node.m_ID);
                    m_Cost = std::move(_node.m_Cost);
                    m_Heuristic = std::move(_node.m_Heuristic);
                    m_Parent = std::move(_node.m_Parent);
                }
                return *this;
            }
```

But the case you are trying to optimize is rare (at best) and this causes the normal case to be worsened (failed branch predication can be very costly). As result I tend to not bother and just use the standard swap technique

```
            Node_& operator =(Node_&& _node) noexcept
            {
                _node.swap(*this);
                return *this;
            }
```

Since you should have a swap method anyway. This also makes writing the move constructor more intuitive as you can also just use the swap method.

Also note your move constructor has undefined behavior.

```
            Node_(Node_&& _node)
            {
                *this = std::move(_node);
            }
```

I know it looks simple. But if this node is default initialized some of its members are in an indeterminate state (as you have no initializer list and some values are POD). When you perform the `std::move` on these members it needs to read them to move their value. If you read a variable that has indeterminate state this is undefined behavior.

If you really on zero initialization in your code to make sure the members are initialized. Then your code becomes brittle. As a change in the use case in a different part of the code may result in the use of default initialization and you are back to undefined behavior. So make sure you initialize all members in a constructor.

I would use the dead simple:

```
            Node_(Node_&& _node) noexcept
                : m_ID()          // IT does assume these values can
                , m_Cost()        // be default initialized but if
                , m_Heuristic()   // I though about it more I am sure 
                , m_Parent()      // we could make it work in all sits.
            {
                _node.swap(*this)
            }
```

Then you add a swap method.

```
            Node_::swap(Node_& other) noexcept
            {
                using std::swap;
                std::swap(m_ID,        _node.m_ID);
                std::swap(m_Cost,      _node.m_Cost);
                std::swap(m_Heuristic, _node.m_Heuristic);
                std::swap(m_Parent,    _node.m_Parent);
            }
```

Using std::forward Vs std::move

I have not had time to understand the algorithm yet so I have no comments on that. But I may come back and have a look if I have time.

Comment: First, sry for the long time to answer.

Comment: You are right, #pragma once is not portable, but it works for my compiler. I use this in all of my code, thus this doesn´t matter here.

You are right, I can avoid the template in the template class. That´s just stupid :D

I have to look at the "noexecpt" keyword, never used it anywhere. Thanks for the remark.

I am not sure, but I think I can not use the std::swap in my move operator. The node class is not compiable, which in fact means, the copy operator/constructor is = delete. swap use copy construction, thus I can not use it.

Comment: The UB in move constructor: I think its not UB, but I might be wrong. I initialize all members in class definition, this should be enough to avoid UB?
I don´t know the exact differences of std::forward vs std::move, but I do not think that move is wrong here.

Comment: std::swap uses move semantics. The method I describe above is the standard way of implementing move semantics. Doing it your way is brittle and susceptible to maintenance problems.

Comment: Yep: Removed the part of std::forward.

Comment: Oh, of course. You are right, std::swap uses move semantics (uses copy only if move not available). Some days ago I used std:swap and got an infinite loop :D